# Can we detect JSON Errors

Tags: php, json

I'm using `json_encode()` and the files that I am using will be parsed to a JavaScript grid.

For example:

`Index.php` has the JavaScript that calls `data.php`, where I parse my PHP arrays to JSON. The question is, is there a way to know if `Index.php` is getting the data right. Some kind of debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox or Chrome's Developer Tools to check your JavaScript.

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

`json_decode` will return `NULL` if it fails:

```
if (json_decode($your_json_var, true) === NULL)
{
    // NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the 
    // encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.
}
```

To make this perfectly save, compare against `'null'` as well:

```
if (json_decode($json, true) === NULL && $json !== 'null')
{
    // NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the 
    // encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.
}
```

It's advised to use PHP 5.3 or higher, it offers access to [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error) which returns `!== JSON_ERROR_NONE` when an error condition did happen.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) can potentially return a literal `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL` value, the only 100% safe way to check for problems is [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error):

```
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
   ... decoded with error ...
}
```

Of course, this was added in PHP 5.3 only. Prior to this, you'd have to check for expected data in the returned structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your Index.php script should return a status code to indicate failure or success.

See [RFC 2616 - 10 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 1):

> ...is there a way that you may know if Index.php is getting the data right. Or some kind of debug?

If you're using a proper client-side debugger (and there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) not to be in 2012!), you can see the data going back and forth to the server using the "Network" tab or similar. I assume you're not expecting `json_encode` to produce invalid JSON so much as not quite the data you were expecting (e.g., you're experimenting with the structure, etc.). You can copy the data that's sent back to the client, and then paste it into http://jsonlint.com to reformat it so you can see the end result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a library such as jQuery for your JavaScript interaction, it can raise an error event if you choose to monitor it. 
See 'error' here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can also call the data.php file directly in your browser see if there data your expecting is what's being returned.